# Convert .mxd to .qgs, MXD2QGS fix?

Tags: convert, python-2.6, mxd, qgs

I've had a look at the following thread about using MXD2QGS and so far I've figured out that this only works with version 10.0 and Python 2.6. I installed MXD2QGS on a machine with Arc10.0 and Python 2.6 and ran the tool.

It's throwing an error:

> No module named ext

I opened the python script and it imports `xml.dom.ext`, so I think this is where the error is occurring. I did some research and it seems to be that this module doesn't come packaged with 2.6 and I think I read that the last version it came with was 2.4. That's fine, but I'm wondering how the developer of this tool created it in 2.6? I couldn't find this module to download, so I'm also wondering if there's a workaround module?

If anyone has some suggestions, I'm all ears.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I've the same problem...do you have found a solution now?
If yes could you help me please?
laura

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1):

A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=xml.dom.ext) found the following Q/A on other sites, one posted by @Mike over on Stack Overflow.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299683/python-2-6-xml-dom-ext-object-missing
- http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/720909-pyxml-package-not-working-no-xml-dom-ext-reader-module-available-after-install

It looks like it is from a now unmaintained "PyXML" module.  And while it appears that it is no longer maintained, it looks like you can still download it from:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxml/?source=directory

Answer (score 0):

mxd2qgs will work without the old module:

```
##import xml.dom.ext
```

if you change:

```
##xml.dom.ext.PrettyPrint(doc, f)
```

to:

```
f.write(doc.toxml())
```

**BUT** The xml is not 'pretty', it doesn't import symbology (the script was never designed to do that), and it doesn't handle geodatabase layers.

(Due credit:
https://dragons8mycat.wordpress.com/2014/04/17/mxd-to-qgis/
https://sites.google.com/site/lumtegis/files/Mxd2Qgs.zip
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python
...thanks!)