# Installing Mxd2Qgs plugin in QGis 2.12

Tags: qgis-plugins, mxd

My purpose is to use the Mxd2Qgs plugin in order to be able to use mxd files with QGis.

I have downloaded the Mxd2Qgs file and unzipped it. I put it in the folder:

```
C:\Program Files\QGis Lyon\apps\qgis\phyton\plugins
```

However, when I open the Plugin Manager in QGis 2.12, the Mxd2Qgs plugin does not appear. How do I resolve this? I have only very basic informatic knowledge (I read similar questions but it did not help me resolve the problem).

Comment: Lambertj is right. There is a problem with versions of pyton script. I tried to do it "mxd2qgisv2.py", correcting by the full path of script, it worked, but some other problems appeared. So, it doesn't work for me to convert arcgis 2 qgis.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144313)

Answer (score 2):

And here is a new version for arcGIS 10.4

https://github.com/oware/Mxd2Qgs

Mxd2Qgs Tool (c)  for ArcGIS 10.4
(c) Copyright Allan Maungu - 2011
Authors: Allan Maungu
Email: lumtegis (at) gmail.com
Modified by :Shiuli Pervin - 2017
Email: Shiuli.pervin@gmail.com

"INSTALL"
1. Unzip Mxd2Qgs.zip anywhere on the Windows system.
2. Run PyXML-0.8.4.win32-py2.6.exe/PyXML-0.8.4.win32-py2.7(for new versions) to install xml.dom.ext python library.
3. Open ArcMap 10. Under Geoprocessing menu click ArcToolbox.
4. Right click ArcToolbox to Add Toolbox.
5. Navigate to Mxd2Qgs folder and select Z_ArcMap to Qgs.tbx (NB - you may need to Connect to Folder)
6. Click Open to load "Z_ArcMap to Qgs.tbx" at the bottom of ArcTools.
7. Right click "ArcMap to Quantum GIS" and select Properties.
8. Specify location of python script file "mxd2qgs.py" and click OK.

"USAGE"
1. Once layers are loaded on an ArcMap document, double click "ArcMap to Quantum GIS"
2. Specify name (with .qgs extension) and location of desired QGIS file and click OK.
3. Open the resulting QGIS file.

Comment: I think @YannX is right-- MXD2QGIS seems to be a plugin for ArcGIS, not QGIS.

Comment: Works with Arcgis 10.6 on WIN7. MXD2QGIS doesn't like french accents, and doesn't get back the symbology. It doesn't like DWG feature class and doesn't like geodatabases, it seems. Tip : dont forget to make sure the toolbox looks at the right script, il looks for mxd2qgs.py but there's a mxd2qgisv2.py in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

MXD2QGS was built as an **ArcToolbox** extension; it is not a QGIS plugin. However, this tool seems that it only works with version 10.0 of ArcGis and Python 2.6. You can see other comments in:

[Convert .mxd to .qgs, MXD2QGS fix?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53897/convert-mxd-to-qgs-mxd2qgs-fix)

https://dragons8mycat.wordpress.com/2014/04/17/mxd-to-qgis/

http://www.faqoverflow.com/gis/23717.html

In Spanish:

http://mappinggis.com/2014/04/mxd2qgis-convierte-tus-mxd-de-arcgis-en-proyectos-de-qgis/

I hope that it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately if I understand well that means that if I don´t have ArcGis there is no way I can get that mxd file converted and I won´t be able to use it in QGis?